# .style.color is working but still throws an error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make HTML paragraph element appear by changing their color. The line where I style the specific elements (multiple elements, its inside a for loop) is throwing an error. It works fine but after that line I cant do anything since the error stops it.

This is the code (its stopped by the chrome tools). U can see that the element is defined, and if I hover over it displays the exact one I need.

[image]

The error message says the element is undefined but I am absolutely sure it is, I have no clue what to do.

[image]

```
const letterIndex = findIndexOfLetter(word, letter.innerHTML);
    for (w = 0; w <= letterIndex.length; w++) {
      var theLetter = wordLetters[letterIndex[w]]
      theLetter.style.color = "azure";
    }
```

Comment: From your first line, I can guess that `letterIndex` is a number, not an array. In the line that reads `var theLetter = ...` you are dealing with it as an array.

Comment: can you provide the code instead of image?

Comment: it is an array, it is an array of the where the letter I wanna highlight is in the string (there can be more then one so i have to use an array)

Comment: Then you need to provide us with the relevant code.

Comment: do you need more?, its kinda a mess i think only this should be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over an array (or an array-like collection, not important here) with the `for` loop, you go

```
for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) { //...
```

and not

```
for (let i = 0; i <= collection.length; i++) { //...
```

With the `<=` stop condition, the last iteration is outside the array.